# How much current does the Eltako ER12-001 need to switch the output?

Tags: current, relay

The Eltako [ER12-001](https://www.eltako.com/fileadmin/downloads/en/_bedienung/ER12_22001601-1_internet_gb.pdf) seems to be an interesting relay.

It has an integrated electronic circuit to operate a bistable relay, while acting like a normal one. The control current can be either AC or DC, but I couldn't find any info on the current required to switch the relay.

I have to make sure that my open collector output can sink enough current to switch this relay. Where can I find the information needed?

Comment: It's possible it might take "no current", the same way MOSFET insulated gates operate. Once the tiny parasitic gate capacitor is charged up to the appropriate voltage, it conducts and no additional current flow is required. This us unlike the way a BJT or electromechanical relay operates.

Comment: @Toor There appears to be some kind of mechanical relay at the insidee of this device, since the datasheet says "Low switching noise" and "Integrated free-wheeling anti-surge diode". How can this relay be switched without current?

Comment: Looks to me like a (normal) [latching relay](http://www.omron.com.au/service_support/FAQ/FAQ02822/index.asp). No information in the datasheet regarding activation or deactivation current.

Comment: @Huisman I don't think this is a normal latching relay. This relay is switching on a rising/falling edge.

Comment: This relay is rated to switch quite substantial wattages, seemingly for building/system automation, so it appears to me that the activation/deactivation current was considered inconsequential compared to the power consumption of the load.  It is not meant for extremely rapid PWM style switching where the precise energy per switching cycle would become relevant.

Comment: I can't understand this datasheet, but if I were designing something of the sort, I'd use a circuit like [this](http://tinyurl.com/y2qwbk3j), if you want some idea of how it might work.

Comment: @someonr I I did not notice the first time that it is bistable or hybrid which would indicate that it does contain an electromechanical relay somewhere so you're right. I was looking at the left column where it says that it uses non-wearing electronic controls.

Comment: @Toor I think it is likely that we are intentionally left in the dark regarding the internal working principle. It is probably their trade secret. I wonder if I could just open a device and probe the schematic or if it is potted.

Comment: It kind of sounds like it just draws a current only momentarily on switching and then stops drawing current (unless it expects you to send a momentary switching signal if you want to conserve power). If that was the case as long as your BJT can handle the momentary heating you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The electronics does not have an internal power supply and therefore no standby loss.
>   The microcontroller is activated when the control contact closes. This switches the bistable
>   relay to the correct direction. The bistable relay switches back either when the control contact
>   opens or when the control voltage falls.

(page 306)

Control current universal control voltage at all control voltages **4** mA ± 20%.

[Source](https://www.eltako.com/fileadmin/downloads/en/_main_catalogue/Gesamt-Katalog_gb_lowRes.pdf), page 312.

Comment: Thanks for finding this page! This is a pretty small current. I'm a little bit surprised.

Comment: Please accept the answer if this was where you were looking for.

Comment: I usually wait some time before I accept an answer. This encourages other people to write an answer, if they can provide additional information.

Answer (score 0):

That is a strange module. There are a couple of points of interest.

The control voltage is listed as 8 - 230 V UC which, apparently, stands for [Universal Current](https://support.industry.siemens.com/tf/WW/en/posts/what-the-means-of-vuc/14581?page=0&pageSize=10) - AC or DC. Meanwhile the datasheets says:

> Integrated free-wheeling anti-surge diode
>   (A1= +, A2 = -).

and this implies a polarity on the power inputs. It is difficult to reconcile these two statements.

[image]

*Figure 1. From the datasheet.*

> I couldn't find any info on the current required to switch the relay.

There is none! I think you'll have to contact them directly.

I would be interested in an analysis of its operation. Buy two and take one apart and tell us how it works.